# ZeroTier not working on router running FreshTomato firmware

Tags: router, tomato

I can successfully connect to my ZeroTier with the router and join my ZT network with an automatic IP assigned my ZT. However, I can’t ping the router from from any device on my ZT network nor have the router ping any device my my ZT network. However any device that’s connected to the router, be it Wi-Fi or wired, could ping all the devices on my ZT network.

My local network IP addresses are 192.168.1.* range and the ZeroTier network is 10.147.18.0/24 My guess its the Iptables rules or route that have to be added or some other configuration I’m missing. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, home, and end user questions will be asked on superuser.com. As this website is intended for Business Administrators who have inquiries regarding their business environment, your inquiry is not be on topic to this particular site.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the information !!